Dryer vent on roof
Does anyone know what type of vent this is? My dryer exhaust exits out of the roof through this vent and I am wondering if it may be filled with lint. Unfortunately, I am not able to access the roof.
Since it is only about 10ft of ducting in my garage going up to the roof I have been able to clear out any lint that may have built up between the dryer and the roof. It has been about two years since this vent was installed.
My question is should this vent be replaced? Could it be causing any issues with the air flow from the dryer?


doesn't look like the right kind of vent cover for a dryer.

That's a flue cap for equipment producing hot gases, such as a water heater or furnace. I seriously doubt that it was installed for a clothes dryer. What's your question, exactly?
